# jqgrid override select row

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid's getGridParam('selarrrow') method. My question is what should be the best and simpler way to override this method so that it can ignore rows with a certain property (like having a disabled checkbox or something)

**EDIT:**

I should make myself a bit more clear.
My grid, has a subgrid and it is initialized with some already selected and 'disabled' rows. On the selectRow event of this subgrid I use

```
onSelectRow : function(rowId, status) {
        listSelected[row_number] = $(this).getGridParam('selarrrow');
},
```

When I select a row from subgrid, the listSelected object for this row has both the newly selected and the one(s) already selected (and disabled) on init

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly, but I suppose you need implement [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) callback which returns `false` to prevent selection of some rows.

Comment: @jose: Sorry, but from the updated part I see that I understand what you do and what you want to have even less as before. Could you describe all more detailed. What you mean under "override select row"? What is you goal?